# Python pandas last and first date of specific key in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with two columns: An object column with duplicate records and a date column. 
What I need is a new dataframe containing the unique objects with the first and last date from the first dataframe

Is there a neat way to filter the original dataframe, create a new one and then do lookup or how would one approach this?

Best regards,
Alex

EDIT:

Very easily solves with a pivot table with the object as index, date as values and aggfunc=max

Comment: please provide an example of input data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate by [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'a': list('aaabbbcccc')})  
print (df)
        Date  a
0 2017-04-03  a
1 2017-04-04  a
2 2017-04-05  a
3 2017-04-06  b
4 2017-04-07  b
5 2017-04-08  b
6 2017-04-09  c
7 2017-04-10  c
8 2017-04-11  c
9 2017-04-12  c

df1 = df.groupby('a')['Date'].agg(['first','last']).reset_index()
print (df1)
   a      first       last
0  a 2017-04-03 2017-04-05
1  b 2017-04-06 2017-04-08
2  c 2017-04-09 2017-04-12
```

Comment: Hi jez. Thank you very much - that was just what I needed! Excellent...